# Change the color of SpriteRenderer in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this method that picks a random color from a preset array of colors.

```
 public Color GetRandomColor()
 {
     return colors[rand.Next(0, colors.Length)];               
 }
```

Then I use it in this method in another class

```
public void RandomizeColors()
{
    for(int i = 0; i< spriteRenderers.Length; i++)
    {    
        spriteRenderers[i].color = rColors.GetRandomColor();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the colors of the sprite renderers all get set to some strange values. The RGB gets set to something in the thousands.

if I use `spriteRenderers[i].color = Color.black` for example it works fine.

I have checked the return values of `GetRandomColor()` and they are all correct. Where am I doing this wrong ?

**Edit:** 
The array of colors. This is part of a constructor:

```
colors = new Color[7];
colors[0] = new Color(87f,72f,161f) ;
colors[1] = new Color(39f,145f,221f);
colors[2] = new Color(233f,191f,57f);
colors[3] = new Color(238f,133f,57f);
colors[4] = new Color(238f,71f,46f);
colors[5] = new Color(193f,57f,235f);
colors[6] = new Color(104f,176f,58f);
```

Comment: Make sure that `GetRandomColor()` return proper color values where each channel should have value between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: can you show us a part of the array `colors`?

Comment: @Pawel Marecki the method returns a color where each channel is between 0 and 255.

Comment: @UriPopov, so i think we found whats the problem. Color have to be converted to 0.0 to 1.0 and everything should works fine.

Comment: I think you can substitute `Color32` if you want to use values `0-255` instead. I'm not sure if there are any caveats, but `Color` and `Color32` seem to be interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html) says you need to have the r, g and b arguments in the range of 0f to 1f. So you can basically divide your r, g and b by 256.

Answer (score 2):

Directly extracted from the Unity Scripting API:

> ## Color
>
> struct in UnityEngine
>
> ### Description
>
> Representation of RGBA colors.
>
> This structure is used throughout Unity to pass colors around. Each color component is a floating point value with a range from **0 to 1**.

Here is the Link to the Documentation:
[Unity Scripting API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html)